# Single LED controlled by two pushbuttons - one of which acts like a toggle switch

Tags: arduino-ide, led, button, switch

Trying to control this LED with those 2 pushbuttons - one button that starts a short flashing sequence, another pushbutton acts like a toggle switch, one press bulb is on, another press bulb is off.

If I switch the LED on and then push the flashing button, the on-off flashing starts but then the LED is shut off because off is the last state of the flashing sequence. How do I make the led turn to original state?

```
#include <ezButton.h>

const int flashing_pin = 2; 
const int switch_pin = 3;
const int led_pin = 8; 

ezButton button(switch_pin);

int ledState = LOW; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(switch_pin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(flashing_pin,INPUT_PULLUP); 
  button.setDebounceTime(50); 
}

void loop() {
  button.loop(); 

  if(button.isPressed()) {
    Serial.println("Press");

    ledState = !ledState;

    digitalWrite(led_pin, ledState); 
  }
  
  if( digitalRead(flashing_pin) == LOW )   {
    doFlash(4);
  }  
}  

void doFlash(uint8_t number_of_times)  {
  while(  number_of_times-- > 0 ) {
    digitalWrite(led_pin,HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(led_pin,LOW);
    delay(250);
  }  
  
}
```

To explain what I want in short;

- if LED is off - flashing sequence works like "ON OFF ON OFF"
- if LED is on - flashing sequence works like "OFF ON OFF ON"

[image]

Comment: `digitalWrite(led_pin,HIGH);` is hardwired ... `digitalWrite(led_pin,!ledstate);` is opposite to current state

Comment: I got it to work! But I'm confused by the loop state, in my original code there's a rule to doFlash(4); and delay 250 - but when using !ledstate, the 4 flashes are no longer 4 time (ON-OFF) cycles, it's half of it, and the 250 delay is double the time, it's half a second....so in order to get the desired "frequency" 4 flashes in 2 seconds, I need to put doFlash 8 and delay 125....can't figure out why :D but it works

Comment: My flash part of the code is this now;

void doFlash(uint8_t number_of_times)  {
  while(  number_of_times-- > 0 ) {
    ledState = !ledState;
    digitalWrite(led_pin, ledState);
    delay(125);
    digitalWrite(led_pin, ledState);
    delay(125);
  }

Comment: i guess is that you have not looked at what you wrote very closely

Comment: `ledState = !ledState` does not belong in the blink code

Comment: I'll fix that - but it does work this way as I intended. But if that's bad practice in coding I'll revise it, I'm learning.

Comment: `the 4 flashes are no longer 4 time (ON-OFF) cycles` ... how is that the way you intended?

Comment: Oh - what I meant is that after I altered the code, the sequencing was correct and at a rate intended. But when I get the time I'll try with the fixed values for loop.